# How can we create Google apps Menu by program?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-chrome-app, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I have an app in Google market place which is tool to make multiple customized application for consumer by himself.

My question is, can we add item in installed app list by coding ? For example: one admin user installed my app called MyBiz, Now through MyBiz he has created apps like MyApp1 ,MyApp2. Now I have to add both app in Installed app list like in below pic.

[image: Adding Item in Menu list]

[image: Adding Item in installed apps list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to currently do this programmatically.

Each App requires it's own Project ID/App ID and Google 
Apps Marketplace (GAM) listing for it to be adding into the Google One Bar's App Launcher.

Within Drive for the New menu, it doesn't require a GAM listing, but does need to be correctly configured in the Developer Console's Google Drive API section.

All this is manual - per app.

Comment: Can we update or modified Manifest file by code via any REST api ? i found there are chrome.contextMenus to manage chrome context menu, Android apk to manage binary in android.                                We need to implement same way in Google apps menu , is there anyway we can request google developers build such api for us ?

Comment: @RamkrishanBhatt not that I'm aware of, although it isn't the manifest file you need to update - rather the configuration in the Developer Console for the Drive SDK (for the Drive New Menu).

Comment: hmm but that does not solve my purpose, actually if i am enabled to create  just hyperlink in of my app which will not be there in marketplace , or google drive apps list (because those app has been created by my app "MyBiz"). I want to create menu item once app will create in "MyBiz" website. Do you any alternative suggestion for me  ?

Comment: @RamkrishanBhatt Agreed, it doesn't. Unfortunately at this time it will require manual action - it cannot be automated as you desire.